# In iOS 16 getting MTU size very low (20)

Tags: ios, ios-bluetooth, ios16

My project based on the CAN2BLE protocol. Here we are communicating with devices using Protobuf framework (https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf). While communicating with BLE device below having some observation

Below iOS 16 MTU Size (iOS 12...15.6.1)
MTU Size Without Response:  244

In iOS 16 MTU Size
MTU Size Without Response:  20

Observation : First time in iOS 16 getting MTU Size Without Response 244, but in second time it will give size 20, but after restarting the device. First time it will gives MTU size 244 from next time MTU size 20. This will happen again and again. Due to this issue my app not getting data form BLE device.